# TypeOf is myType

Tags: .net, vb.net, typeof

Public MyObj as Object

```
Public Function Test(t as Type) as Boolean
 Return TypeOf MyObj is t ' does not work
End Function
```

Thanks.

## * EDIT

====================================================================

For clarity I will use a complete example, a little modified that initially was thought.

I use an interface, and would like to know if the objects(implementing I) passed in argument are the same type as a internal field(**I; A:I; AA:A; B:I**).

First of all, **(a)** I need the exact class identification (only *A=A, B=B, AA=AA*)
and I'd like also **(b)** to have a "inheritance equivalency" (*A=A and A=AA but A<>B*)

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1
  ' object to test
  Private objI As I

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim aObj As New A
    Dim aaObj As New AA
    Dim bObj As New B

    'assing the object to test - A
    Me.objI = New A

    'test it
    MessageBox.Show(SameTypeAs(aObj).ToString()) ' need True here
    MessageBox.Show(SameTypeAs(bObj).ToString()) ' need False here
    MessageBox.Show(SameTypeAs(aaObj).ToString()) ' need a)Flase and b)True here
  End Sub

  Function SameTypeAs(ByVal iObj As I) As Boolean
    ' here is the "problem":
    ' how to detect the same (sub)types of I?
    Return Me.objI Is iObj
  End Function

  ' interface..........
  Interface I
  End Interface

  ' class A..........
  Class A
    Implements I
  End Class

  ' class B..........
  Class B
    Implements I
  End Class

  ' class AA..........
  Class AA
    Inherits A
  End Class
End Class
```

Comment: And what's the problem? "does not work" is not exactly descriptive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, for a) point I seem to find a solution:

```
  Function SameTypeAs(ByVal iObj As I) As Boolean
    Return CType(iObj, Object).GetType Is CType(Me.objI, Object).GetType()
  End Function
```

or the generic variant

```
  Function SameTypeAs(Of T As I)() As Boolean
    Return TypeOf Me.objI Is T
  End Function
```

as for the b)...

Comment: Why are you using CType here? Just calling GetType directly should be fine.

Comment: No, I think I need to use DirectCast, because is run-time optimal.

Directly GetType i can't, because of interface.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of comparing types for equality, you probably want to use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

```
return t.IsAssignableFrom(MyObj.GetType())
```

If you look at the the [`TypeOf ... Is ...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx) operator documentation you'll see it requires a type *name* as the second operand. This type name is resolved at compile-time.

EDIT: If you really want *exact* equality, then `TypeOf ... Is ...` wouldn't have worked for you anyway.

As for the difference, consider:

```
MyObj = New MemoryStream()

...

Dim result = Test(GetType(Stream))
```

Do you want `result` to be true or false? If you want it to be false, you should use simple equality:

```
return t is MyObj.GetType()
```

If you want it to be true because `MyObj` is *assignment compatible* with `Stream`, you should use the code at the top of this answer. That would be the behaviour of `TypeOf MyObject Is Stream`, which is why it was my initial answer.

EDIT: Okay, answering the changed question:

```
Function SameTypeAs(ByVal iObj As I) As Boolean
  Return Me.objI.GetType() = iObj.GetType()
End Function

Function CompatibleType(ByVal iObj As I) As Boolean
  Return Me.objI.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(iObj.GetType())
  ' Or this depending on which way round you want compatibility
  ' Return iObj.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(Me.objI.GetType())
End Function
```

Note that this isn't null-safe - if you pass in `Nothing` or if `Me.objI` is nothing, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` on the call to `GetType()`.

Comment: just an add: what if instead of **t as Type** where *obj as Object*?

Comment: @serhio: I can't see how that would help.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do:

```
Return GetType(MyObj).Equals(t)
```

Comment: @serhio: Sorry, I mean that `TypeOf ... Is ...` requires a compile-time type. If you use `Return MyObj is t` that will *only* return true if MyObj is exactly `GetType(Type)` - it's comparing the *value* of `MyObj` with the *type* `t`, rather than the *type* of the value of `MyObj`.